# How can I print a one dimensional array as grid in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have an array of 200 items.

```
grid = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 .... and so on]
```

How can I print it as a 2D array like so? Split it every 10 characters actually.

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

I have tried things such as

```
def Print(grid):
    for i in grid:
        if(len(i) % WIDTH-1 == 0):
            print(i)
        else:
            print(i, end = ' ')
```

with no success.

Comment: So every 10 characters is a column? What if the grid does not evenly divide by 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate of the length of `grid`, in this case `200` by `10` and use that as the start for your slicing, printing that plus 9 additional values.

```
grid = [0]*200
for x in range(0,len(grid),10):
    print(grid[x:x+9])
```

edit:  This will print slices of the list, which is still a list which is why you see the brackets.  Like others have shown you can use join and map to print it as a comma separated string if you really need to:

```
grid = [0]*200
for x in range(0,len(grid),10):
    print(','.join(map(str,grid[x:x+9])))
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: That is great. Any ideas why it is also printing brackets and commas, besides the values?

Comment: @IAmNotARobot  It's printing a slice of the list.  I have updated the answer to show how you could convert that into a string.

Comment: This works great print(' '.join(map(str,grid[x:x+10]))) and actually what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @IAmNotARobot That will actually print 11 digits if you use +10 btw

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using slicing:

```
a = [0 for i in range(200)]

for i in range(len(a) // 10):
    sub_list = a[i * 10:(i + 1) * 10]
    print(', '.join(map(str, sub_list)))
```

Although this can be compressed to a single line with some list comprehensions, it would then become very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

try `np.matrix`

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.array([0]*100)
B = np.reshape(grid, (-1, len(grid)//10))
print(np.matrix(B))
```

---

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

**OR**

```
for i in B:
    print(', '.join(map(str, i)))
```

---

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
row_length = 10
for row in [grid[i:i + row_length] for i in range(0, len(grid), row_length)]:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
grid = [0]*200
print(*[grid[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(grid), 10)], sep='\n')
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and compact solution, without any external references and exatly your stated output:

```
for s in [[n for n in grid[i:i+10]] for i in range(0, len(grid), 10)]:
    print(str(s)[1:-1]+',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for a 9-element list, creating sublists of 3 items each:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
largelst = []
smalllst = []

arraysize = 3

counter = 0
for element in lst:
    smalllst.append(element)
    counter += 1
    if counter == arraysize:
        largelst.append(smalllst)
        smalllst = []
        counter = 0
print(largelst)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

This works by iterating through the items in `lst`, and appending them to `smalllst`. Each iteration of the loop, `counter` is increased by 1. Every `arraysize` iterations (in this case, every 3), `smalllst` is appended to `largelst`, `counter` is reset to 0, and `smalllst` is reset to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that can handle non-square data.

```py
dataLen = 35
rowLen = 6
data = ["0"] * dataLen

remainder = dataLen % rowLen
n_rows = (dataLen - remainder) / rowLen

start = 0
end = rowLen

for row in range(int(n_rows)):
    print(data[start:end])
    start += rowLen
    end += rowLen

if remainder != 0:
    print(data[-remainder:])
```